# Installing Clean on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, functional-programming, osx-yosemite

I've tried to install Clean on my new MBP with Yosemite. I've downloaded the latest stable release from the official site (http://clean.cs.ru.nl/Download_Clean#Mac_OS_X) but after "make"-ing it I've tried to compile a simple example module but received the following:

```
$ clm hamming
Compiling hamming
clm: can't start the clean compiler: No such file or directory
```

Any ides would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
ZTorok

Comment: Have you installed the Apple Xcode tools? You need to go to the AppStore and install Xcode tools then run the following in Terminal... `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thanks, but I have it installed already.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem (though I installed Clean via homebrew). Any help would be appreciated!